# Injecting modules into service AngularJS ES6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-service

I'm new to ES6 syntax of within Angular. I'm trying to create a service and use `$http` and `LocalStorageModule`

When I try to inject the two modules into my service I get errors about my syntax not being in strict mode. What am I doing wrong?

**services/auth.js**

```
export default class {

  constructor($http, localStorageService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
  }
}
```

**services/index.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';

import auth from './auth';

export default angular
  .module( 'app.services', [] )
  .service( 'Authentication', auth )
  .name;
```

Using Angular 1.4.5

Comment: Does the error go away if you enable strict mode for your module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using `'ngInject';` in the constructor function.

I believe it wasn't working because when `'ngInject'` lets Babel transpiler know how to handle this injection

```
export default class {

  constructor($http, localStorageService) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$http = $http;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To correctly achieve this, without relying on transpilers, simply add a static getter to your class, like this...

```
export class {
  constructor($http, localStorageService) {
    // Store references to the $http and localStorageService providers
    this.$http = $http;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
  }

  static get $inject() {
    return ['$http', 'localStorageService'];
  }
}
```

AngularJS will acknowledge the `$inject` property on the given class and handle your dependency injection accordingly.

---

- `$inject`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di/#-inject-property-annotation